# Mcrypt Win32 vs. PHP Mcrypt extension

Tags: php, mcrypt

I'm looking forward encrypting a file using Win32 command-line mcrypt.exe. Then decrypt it using an apache/unix based PHP script.

So I do in win's command-line:

```
mcrypt -a "blowfish" -k 1234 -m cbc test.txt
```

(`test.txt` is a simple text file that contains "working fine"

This generates a 47 bytes files named `test.txt.nc`

So I upload the file to my apache webserver and run this script:

```
$s = mcrypt_cbc("blowfish","1234",file_get_contents("test.txt.nc"),MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
file_put_contents("newtext.txt",$s);
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: mcrypt_cbc() [function.mcrypt-cbc]: Attempt to use an empty IV, which is NOT recommend
```

And a 48 bytes `newtext.txt` file, which contains binary data instead of the decrypted text file

I need some guidance!. Thank you very much

Comment: [mcrypt_cbc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-cbc.php) seems to be somewhat deprecated and should be exchanged for [mcrypt_generic()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php) och [mdecrypt_generic()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mdecrypt-generic.php).

Comment: i'm using mcrypt_generic now, but it seems i can't get to decrypt a win32 mcrypt encoded file even using the same algorithm